# Git Extensions - pushing to a non master remote branch

Tags: git, git-extensions

using v2.49
Git version 2.10.1

I'm facing a problem in the push dialog under the following scenario:

- Remote repository has 2 branches, 'master' and 'otherBranch'
- cloning a local repository and checks out the 'otherBranch' branch.
- creating a new branch called 'myBranch' and checks it out.
- changing    a file, -staging and commiting my changes.
- Trying to push 'myBranch' into remote 'otherBranch' but the push dialog shows           only 'master' and 'myBranch' as options for "branch to push to" (missing the    'otherBranch' option).

Git Extension view is aware of otherBranch (I can see the split from master into origin/otherBranch branch).
Tried also to git fetch and pull but everything is up to date.

Now, when using Linux GIT command line, "git push" works correctly on this specific scenario ("git push origin myBranch:otherBranch"), so it is just like git extensions doesn't get the remote branches list correctly.
What am I missing?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Perhaps Git extensions doesn't know that the `otherBranch` branch exists on the remote.  If so, then doing a `git fetch` might fix that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tim, added some new information.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in GitExtensions. https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/commit/8d9560230041f27ecf72255a542e095532be722a
The patch will be included in the 2.50 version.